# Android apk works different in different devices

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android app. I have been testing it with the AVD (Nexus 5 API 22) and my LG G2 (5.0.2). When I released my first beta version I used a Moto G (4.4.4) to test it, and it works completely different.

E.g., when clicking a button, in the Moto G an item is added twice to a ListView, whereas in the other two works fine. Also in the G2 the background is not displayed, and in the other two it can be seen perfectly.

Right now I have tested it in a Xperia U (4.0.4) and everything works fine.

The Android Studio is configured for the API 15 in compiledSdkVersion, minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion.

What's happening? I don't understand anything. What can I do to fix it?

EDIT: I add code snippets where the app fails.
TimePickerFragment class

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
     Alarm pickedAlarm = new Alarm();
     int pk;

     pickedAlarm.setHour(hourOfDay);
     pickedAlarm.setMinute(minute);
     pickedAlarm.setActivity(getActivity());

     pk = db.insertNewAlarm(hourOfDay, minute);

     pickedAlarm.set_id(pk);
     pickedAlarm.setAdapter(adapter);
     pickedAlarm.setDb(db);

     adapter.add(pickedAlarm);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

     pickedAlarm.startCountdown(false);

     Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Alarm set and countdown started.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

It seems that in Moto G this function is called twice...

MainActivity, when there is the botton to show the timePicker:

```
public void addAlarmClick(View view) {
    TimePickerFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
    timePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

Comment: could you post some code? In my opinon it's the way it is written not the android sdk

Comment: I guess all you gotta change is Target SDK, where you should compile with latest SDK

Comment: @Yousef's I just compiled it withe the latest SDK (API 22) and just does the same.